# what's the difference between SHA1CryptoServiceProvider vs HMACSHA1

Tags: c#, encryption, hash, oauth, cryptography

I'm wondering what the difference between these hashing functions in:

```
System.Security.Cryptography
```

They seem to be returning different results. In the past, I've used HMACSHA1 successfully with a key.

But now i need a keyless hash and SHA1CryptoServiceProvider seems to be returning the right result. Which has me wondering why i need to suddenly switch to a different class. It's hard to find information about this. Example:

```
// y1 = "2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=" (seems correct)
var f1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
string y1 = Convert.ToBase64String(f1.ComputeHash(new byte[] { }));

// y2 = "+9sdGxiqbAgyS31ktx+3Y3BpDh0=" (seems wrong)
HMAC f2 = HMACSHA1.Create();
f2.Key = new byte[]{};
string y2 = Convert.ToBase64String(f2.ComputeHash(new byte[] { }));
```

**EDIT**:

Context: I'm trying to implement OAuth 1.0 with SHA512, because i couldn't find a .NET library that does (i'm aware that SHA1 is weak). I already have the signature calculation using HMACSHA1.Create() although the Create call may not be doing what i expect as one of you pointed out. I was looking into implementing the oauth_body_hash parameter:

https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-eaton-oauth-bodyhash-00.html#anchor16

That's when i noticed that HMACSHA1.Create() was not creating the correct hash even though it worked for the the oauth_signature. SHA1CryptoServiceProvider did work for the oauth_body_hash though. The idea of using SHA1 is that there are more examples online. Afterwards i want to change it for SHA512

Comment: They're not really interchangeable, they're different beasts altogether. More context might help get better answers.

Comment: FYI: `HMACSHA1.Create` doesn’t exist, you’re calling HMAC.Create, which happens to return HMACSHA1.

Comment: @bartonjs oh. i had no idea it was a derived method. thanks for pointing that out. that probably explains why i wasn't getting the expected results from HMACSHA512.Create()

Comment: @JamesKPolk added some context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HMAC is a type of MAC, that is message authentication code. It is used when you need e.g. to verify that the message you received is indeed from someone you trust (i.e. you own a key to verify that).

SHA-1 is just a hash function without any verification, i.e. just a thumbprint. Can be used e.g. to verify that the downloaded file ix correct (i.e. if you know a hash from a website, you can download a file, calculate hash and figure out that it is equal to a given one)

Also I advise against writing your own OAuth libraries unless you really know what you are doing or have other options (i.e. well known trusted libraries) that I suggest that you use.

Comment: thanks for the info. i'm open to suggestions for OAuth 1.0 .NET libraries that can use SHA256 OR SHA512 (i haven't found any). i'm not implementing my own cryptographic functions (i'm using built in .NET functions)

Comment: i'm also not dealing with tokens. it's a very simple subset where i just check signatures in messages i receive, so i'm not that concerned

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about such libraries, I assume that default Microsoft implementation UseJwtBearer should be able to do that, but not sure

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use sha1. Use sha256.

The difference is that HMAC is a keyed hash. That means that the hash output is based on a given key. The hash of "test" with the key "123" for example is different then the hash of "test" with the key "456"

Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyed-Hash_Message_Authentication_Code

Comment: thanks. i'm not planning on using SHA1 in the final version. i was hoping that providing an empty byte array as key would be the same as using a keyless hash. but i'm starting to get the impression that it isn't the case